# Bitcoin ticker + fontawesome

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, bitcoin, ticker

My task was to write a function that gets Bitcoin trades from JSON link, change interval with buttons, add fontawesome arrow up/down/line depends if the rate went up/down/no change and display it on the website.

I have everything except fontawesome...

My HTML code is:

```
<h3>Bitcoin to PLN</h3>
<h4>Buy</h4>
<div id="buy"><p></p></div>
<h4>Sell</h4>
<div id="sell"><p></p></div>
<h4>Refresh in:</h4>

<form name="timerBtn">
<input type="button" class="button" id="btn5" value="5 s">
<input type="button" class="button" id="btn10" value="10 s">
<input type="button" class="button" id="btn30" value="30 s">
<input type="button" class="button" id="btn60" value="60 s">
</form>

<p id="timer">Refreshing in 5 sekund</p>
```

And JS:

```
$("form").click( function(getTimer) {
    if (getTimer.target.className === 'button') {

        $("p#timer").empty();

        var timer = $("p#timer").append( "Refresh in " + getTimer.target.value);

    }
    return timer
});

function startRefresh() { $.getJSON("https://blockchain.info/pl/ticker", function (data) {
        $("#buy").html(data.PLN.buy);
         $("#sell").html(data.PLN.sell);
        console.log ("reupload");
});    

}

setTimer = setInterval(startRefresh, 5000);

$("input#btn5").click( function() {
   clearInterval(setTimer);
    setTimer = setInterval(startRefresh, 5000);

});

$("input#btn10").click( function() {
   clearInterval(setTimer);
    setTimer = setInterval(startRefresh, 10000);

});

$("input#btn30").click( function() {
   clearInterval(setTimer);
    setTimer = setInterval(startRefresh, 30000);

});

$("input#btn60").click( function() {
   clearInterval(setTimer);
    setTimer = setInterval(startRefresh, 60000)

});
```

I don't know how to deal with fontawesome part

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: There are [examples on the Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) site.

Comment: Ok, but how to change arrow if value displayed is bigger/lower than value before refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome arrow up is displayed like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
```

I would store all those html snippets (up, down and no change) into their own variables.

```
upArrow = '<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>'
```

And then inject them when you inject the hmtl in the `startRefresh` function like this:

```
$("#buy").html(upArrow + data.PLN.buy);
```